# Need to recover my MacBook keychain with all my passwords in it

Tags: mac, keychain

I didn't know my keychain login password and in the process of trying to figure out how to reset it, I accidentally reset my whole keychain. Now all my passwords are gone! Is there a way to recover them?

Comment: Give this a shot. [Restore OS X Keychain](https://superuser.com/questions/487880/restore-os-x-keychain). It could potentially be different if you're on macOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore OS X Keychain](https://superuser.com/questions/487880/restore-os-x-keychain)